# SQL insert trigger vs replication or stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 SQL Server tables that are linked via a link server connection. I have placed the following trigger on one table to fire as soon as a record is inserted into the one table and copies it across to my other table. However if the link should break for some reason or the other server goes down my trigger wont fire is its  instantaneous only.

What would be the best recommendation to handle this situation?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON  [cms].[dbo].[HA_TRANSIT]
FOR INSERT
AS  
    INSERT INTO [10.230.1.56].[wfcdb].[dbo].[PunchDataHoneywell](card_number, identifier, name, surname, transit_date, terminal, direction, exported) 
       SELECT 
          card_number, identifier, name, surname, transit_date, terminal, direction, exported = '0'
       FROM inserted
```

Comment: This is exactly the reason to use replication rather than a trigger. You now have a database that is only as reliable as *both* of your servers and the network between them.

Comment: An additional reason would be INSERT performance. Reflecting changes to another server could slow down the operation. Agree with Damien replication is better.

Comment: To add, if there's a problem with linked server inside the trigger, not only the insert will not be propagated but the original transaction on the source database will be rolled back as well.

Answer (score -2):

Database replication is best way to synchronize two tables on different server. For mor detail go through :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Comment: You have not given any indication as to why replication is better than triggers for the users, use case, not have you reference which part of the URL is applicable